# How to Ping a web service method which is having return type void

Tags: java, web-services, ping

Hi I have a web service class in service proxy which is having a method which returns void. I have to check whether the service is up and active. Since the method is returning void i am not able to get the status of the service.  Is there any way to check the status of this web service method by using or without using ping?

Below is my webservice method which is having return type void. This web service method will do some validations and trigger another method so that it will not return any value.

```
 @GET
        @Path("/triggers/{name}")
        public void triggerMethod(@PathParam("name") String triggername, @Context HttpServletRequest aHttpRequest){
            //code

    }
```

Below is the code already existing for ping function, but it will check the status from the response. This code is working for the webservices  methods which is returnig response and accepts APPLICATION_JSON.

```
    private void invoketrigger(ServiceDataDTO myData){

            try{
        target.request().headers(getRequestHeaders()).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
                    WebTarget target = client.target(myData.getServiceURI());
                    Response response = target.request().headers(getRequestHeaders()).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
                    if(response.getStatus() == 200){
                        status = "green";
            }
    }




 The code which I tried for my method is given below.

 private void invoketrigger(ServiceDataDTO myData){

        try{
    target.request().headers(getRequestHeaders()).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        URL url = new URL(myData.getServiceURI());
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        int response = connection.getResponseCode();

        if(response == 200){
            myData.setServiceStatus(ServicesDashboardConstants.STATUS_OK);
        }
        }catch( Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: response.ok should be returned

Answer (score 1):

I'm completely sure that you can't do that without returning anything. the client side will not know if the request is done or not unless if the service returned is OK, 
otherwise the client side will wait for the response.
so you have to make your method returning an object of type Response. and you don't need to add anything to response just tell the method to return 200  with

```
response.ok (200) ; // this will tell the method what is the status code response
```